# How to fix WebApp keeps rendering state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm setting up a simple weather app using React and Hooks. However, I found out that the app keeps fetching API. How can I stop this?

```
function WeatherInfo (props) {
    const [wind,setWind] = useState(undefined);
    const [precipitation,setPrecipitation] = useState(undefined);
    const [humidity,setHumidity] = useState(undefined);
    const [pressure,setPressure] = useState(undefined);

    if (props.city) {
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=metric&APPID=af081727ae6d5c4cbe2cd266b726e632`).then(results => {return results.json();}
            ).then(data => setWind(data.wind.speed))
        })
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=a5bf94fc16c84928acb114156182311&q=${props.city}&num_of_days=1&tp=24&format=json`).then(results => {return results.json();}
            ).then(data => setPrecipitation(data.data.weather[0].hourly[0].chanceofrain))
        })
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=metric&APPID=af081727ae6d5c4cbe2cd266b726e632`).then(results => {return results.json();}
            ).then(data => setPressure(data.main.pressure))
        })        
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=metric&APPID=af081727ae6d5c4cbe2cd266b726e632`).then(results => {return results.json();}
            ).then(data => setHumidity(data.main.humidity))
        })


    }
    return (
        <div>
            {props.city &&  
            <div>
                <p>Wind of {props.city} is {wind}</p>
                <p>Chance of rain of {props.city} is {precipitation}%</p>
                <p>Humidity of {props.city} is {humidity}</p>
                <p>Pressure of {props.city} is {pressure}</p>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default WeatherInfo;
```

Expect Result: Function only fetchs API once a while

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not super familiar with react but it looks like you're just showing one component out of context. My guess is there's some state change that's triggering the fetch calls in this component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `useEffect` hook is run on every rerender. If you don’t want that, you can specify a second optional argument, see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects.

In your specific case: you probably only want to execute the effect when the city changes, so:
`useEffect(/* callbacks as before */, [props.city])`.

Furthermore, you should only call hooks at the top level (I.e. not in ifs): https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#%EF%B8%8F-rules-of-hooks. You can move the if branching into the callbacks of useEffect

Answer (score -1):

you could use setInterval to limit how often the code runs like

```
setInterval(function(){
    if (props.city) {
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=metric&APPID=af081727ae6d5c4cbe2cd266b726e632`).then(results => {return results.json();}
            ).then(data => setWind(data.wind.speed))
        })
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=a5bf94fc16c84928acb114156182311&q=${props.city}&num_of_days=1&tp=24&format=json`).then(results => {return results.json();}
            ).then(data => setPrecipitation(data.data.weather[0].hourly[0].chanceofrain))
        })
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=metric&APPID=af081727ae6d5c4cbe2cd266b726e632`).then(results => {return results.json();}
            ).then(data => setPressure(data.main.pressure))
        })        
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${props.city}&units=metric&APPID=af081727ae6d5c4cbe2cd266b726e632`).then(results => {return results.json();}
            ).then(data => setHumidity(data.main.humidity))
        })}}, 10000);
```

then just adjust the time for how often you want it to check

Comment: That’s not how React hooks work. They have to be on the top level of the Component to work correctly. So you’d either have to use the native filtering of useEffect,with the second, optional argument or do custom filtering in the useEffect itself.